# Bootstrap Navbar alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sorry if the answer to my question is really simple but here it is. So I need to put an image and nav bar in the header of the webpage and have them aligned so that the image is to the left and the nav bar is to the right. I have tried changing the "float" attribute however the nav bar and image are still stacked on top of each other. The image below should hopefully show you what I mean.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<header>
  <img src="White Logo.png" id="logo"/>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="mNavbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <a href="#start"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</header>
```

Here is the image (the box is where the logo will be):
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v31gQ.png)

Comment: The image you link appears to be an example of what you want, not of the white box itself.

Comment: @MattD Yeah the image is showing what I want.

Comment: Right, so if you want people to help you mock up an example of how to get that, you need to include the image you plan to use for branding. You refer to it as "the image", which leads me to believe this is the image you want in the brand section, but it's actually an example of what you want, which doesn't help.

Comment: @MattD I'm not understanding what you mean. All I need to know is how to code my HTML and CSS so that it aligns the logo and nav bar the way I want it, which is shown in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [official Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image), you need to replace the text used in navbar-brand with your image of choice.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="...">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The image tag after the anchor tag is where you'd want to place the image.

The top of your navbar markup should look like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
```

Where you see the text for Brand in there is where you'll place your image.

Comment: Thanks I had tried that before however after messing with the css, I got it to work. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: It's all good. The navbar in the current version of Bootstrap is very frustrating to work with.